# Text is not aligned properly on row

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

See the following example:

[image]

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2">
        <p>Error</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-8">
        <div class="progress error" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom">
          <div class="progress-bar error-bar" role="progressbar"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <a tabindex="0" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="Some random text">
          <i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true" style="vertical-align: top"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The text "Error" is not vertically aligned properly with the prograss bar and font awesome icon.  I tried adding `vertical-align: top` to `<p>` but it did not make a difference. How do I correctly vertically align the text?

Comment: try `line-height` to `p`

Answer (score 1):

You can add `line-height: 1rem;` to `<p>`

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the class `align-items-center` to your `row`, this will make all cols vertically aligned in the center of the row.

If you have any question about the Bootstrap grid system, check out [the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/), that's pretty good by the way.

The property `vertical-align` only applies to inline and table cells elements, check out [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) about that. So, `vertical-align` will only work if your `<p>` element is an inline element, and if has enough height to be aligned.

Comment: It did change something... but now the "Error" text is too high instead of too low.